# Change time of owlcarousel

Tags: javascript

I have following owlCarousel code, which changes 3 different pictures (like a slideshow). I want to change now the changing time. Every picture should appear 8 Second, then next. I am struggling to change the correct parameters. Can someone help?

```
f.fn.owlCarousel.options = {
    items: 5,
    itemsCustom: !1,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
    itemsTablet: [768, 2],
    itemsTabletSmall: !1,
    itemsMobile: [479, 1],
    singleItem: !1,
    itemsScaleUp: !1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 10000,
    slideSpeed: 200,
    paginationSpeed: 900,
    rewindSpeed: 1e3,
    stopOnHover: !1,
    navigation: !1,
    navigationText: ["prev", "next"],
    rewindNav: !0,
    scrollPerPage: !1,
    pagination: !0,
    paginationNumbers: !1,
    responsive: !0,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
    responsiveBaseWidth: g,
    baseClass: "owl-carousel",
    theme: "owl-theme",
    lazyLoad: !1,
    lazyFollow: !0,
    lazyEffect: "fade",
    autoHeight: !1,
    jsonPath: !1,
    jsonSuccess: !1,
    dragBeforeAnimFinish: !0,
    mouseDrag: !0,
    touchDrag: !0,
    addClassActive: !1,
    transitionStyle: !1,
    beforeUpdate: !1,
    afterUpdate: !1,
    beforeInit: !1,
    afterInit: !1,
    beforeMove: !1,
    afterMove: !1,
    afterAction: !1,
    startDragging: !1,
    afterLazyLoad: !1,
};
```

Comment: You need to change `autoplayTimeout`

Comment: I tried, but nothing happens when I change this parameter

Comment: Try with removing `autoplay:true`. It autoplays the slides with default timer.